# npm script strange behavior using npm terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have this in my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.37.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.11.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.20",
    "selenium-server": "^3.11.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "e2e": "nightwatch -c tests/nightwatch.conf.js -e chrome"
}
```

and I'm able to execute `npm run e2e`

But in my terminal when I do `node nightwatch -c tests/nightwatch.conf.js -e chrome` I got this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\James\Documents\sample_project\nightwatch'
```

Just curious, what's the problem? I doubt I know how npm and node work now.

Comment: did u do npm install?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path

Comment: this is an issue with windows, you have to specify the absolute path

Comment: @0.sh meaning mac worked fine? yes I'm on wnidows

Comment: Try `node_modules/.bin/nightwatch -c tests/nightwatch.conf.js -e chrome` which should work since that's where in binary is installed.  The reason it works from `npm run` is because `npm run` includes `node_modules/.bin` to the path.

Comment: Because `nightwatch` will actually be in `node_modules/.bin` as per the package install. Using `npm run` ( which is what happens to scripts ) will pick this up. As will `node_modules/.bin/nightwatch -c tests/nightwatch.conf.js -e chrome`. That's what's actually happening here, and it's certainly covered many times before in pre-existing answers.

Comment: @generalhenry it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Is `nightwatch` module installed globally? If not, then install this module globally first using `npm install nightwatch -g`. As you are using this module inside CLI command, hence this must be installed globally in the system.

> Sometime there might be issue with *npm cache*. Try to clean up the npm cache using:
>
> `npm cache verify`
> `npm cache clean --force`
> `npm cache clear --force`
>
> Then you can run `npm install` and `npm install nightwatch -g` again, just to make sure all modules are installed.

**Moreover, you can try to use `--verbose` in your command like:**

```
node nightwatch.js --verbose
```

And see the output, may be this help to debug the issue.

Comment: she already has the nightwatch in package.json so she can just do 'npm install'  to install the modules, if she hasnt already

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd correct, I won't be able to run nightwatch if I haven't do `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

When you do 'node nightwatch' it should go into node_modules folder and look for nightwatch, but instead its looking in the root directory. 
You could cut the nightwatch folder in node_modules and move it to the same directory as package.json. Give it a try!

Comment: that's bad idea coz what if I do npm install in my server? it will have duplicate nightwatch folder

Comment: I agree its a bad practice, but somehow its not redirecting to node_modules folder to look for nightwatch but instead the root folder. So that's an alternative